# Is there something wrong with wrapping <label> around other elements?

Tags: html, label

I'd like to have three cells in a table select the appropriate checkbox when you click on them, so I wrapped them with a label tag.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="input_id" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <label for='input_id'>
      <td>stuff</td>
      <td>stuff</td>
      <td>stuff</td>
    </label>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately this broke the click functionality. Normally when you click the text in a label it toggle the check, but this doesn't work with wrapped elements. Any ideas why? Should it, or is there some reason this is a bad idea?

Interestingly, it does work if I use three separate labels around the cell contents with the same 'for' attribute....

Comment: I just ran a test, and it works on Chrome.  Which browser are you using?  Technically, this not valid HTML.  You would need to have <table> and <tr> tags inside the label to be valid, which might help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to make my html validity the point of the question. I've updated the structure to be less confusing. I was using chrome, and could only get it to work if I wrapped each cell contents in a label. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/rxwHp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to write invalid mark-up as per your example. The only element that should wrap a `td` is a `tr`.

As it stands, your example won't break the click functionality, because the td tags will be discarded by the parser.

However, if the example was inside a table and tr element, then the input and label elements would be moved to before the table, and therefore wouldn't be wrapping either the `td`s or the "stuff" text (which stay inside the table), so clicking on that text will have no effect.

Comment: Even after 'un-omitting' the rest of the table elements that is exactly what happens, but what reasoning is there behind that behavior? Shouldn't you be able to use any amount of elements in a label as long as they are actually labels for the input?

Comment: Really, the reasoning is that it has to work that way to make browsers capable of handling old HTML. Some old browser (probably Netscape 2 or 3 in this case) that dominated the market at one time did it that way, web pages came to rely on it, so all modern browsers have to do it that way too. As a result, some parsing rules are beyond strange, you just have to accept that's how it has to be.